# separate window in tkinter giving result

Tags: python-2.7, tkinter

I have been trying to make a simple calculator but I am struggling mainly with two things.

1. Making a function that performs arithmetic equations in tkinter
2. Showing the result in separate window

I've attempted to show the results in a new window by using toplevel widget and showMessagebox but none of them works!

Code:

```
from Tkinter import *
import math
import tkMessageBox

class Calculator():

     def __init__(self,master):

          self.master = master
          self.master.configure(background='sky blue')
          self.master.geometry('650x420+350+225')

          self.master.title('Calculator')

          self.ini_velocity = DoubleVar()

          # here we start creating buttons and entry boxes
          self.m_label = Label(text='Calculator',fg = 'Navy', font=("Helvetica", 20,"bold italic"), bg='sky blue')
          self.m_label.pack()

          self.button1 = Button(self.master,text='Final velocity',fg='white',bg='dark green',bd =3, width=12, command= self.show_m)
          self.button1.place(x=52,y=155)

          self.label1=Label(self.master,text='''1. v = u + a*t

     Initial Velocity

     Acceleration

          Time ''', fg= 'Navy', font='Helvetica 10 bold',bg='sky blue')
          self.label1.place(x=0,y=30)

          self.e1= Entry(self.master, textvariable = self.ini_velocity, width=4,bd=2)
          self.e1.place(x=120, y=62)

          self.e2= Entry(self.master, width=4, bd=2)
          self.e2.place(x=120, y=92)

          self.e3=Entry(self.master, width=4,bd=2)
          self.e3.place(x=120, y=122)

     def my_calculation(self): # this function is to operate the calculation
          root2 = Toplevel(self.master)
          myGUI = result_window(root2)

     def my_quit(self):
          self.master.destroy()

     def myresault(self):
          self.a = self.ini_velocity.get()


class result_window ():
     def __init__(self,master):
          self.master = master
          self.master.configure(background='sky blue')
          self.master.geometry('250x175+150+125')
          self.master.title('resault')

          print (Calculator.self.e1.get())

     def F_velocity(self):
          ini_v = self.ini_velocity.get()
          print (ini_v)


          # end of button commands
def main():

     root = Tk()
     myGUIcalculator = Calculator(root)
     root.mainloop()

if __name__=='__main__':
     main()
```

Comment: "None of them works" is too vague.

Answer (score 0):

For the separate window, use `tkMessageBox`(as you thought). use `tkMessageBox.showinfo(title, message)`. Example:

```
from Tkinter import *
import tkMessageBox

numbersandoperatorslist = "1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 0 - + = / *".split(" ")

def operation(content):
    contentlist = []
    for char in range(len(content)):
        contentlist.append(char) # This might be useful later
        if char not in numbersandoperatorslist:
            tkMessageBox.showerror("Error", "Your operation has an undefined character.")
            return
    result = eval(content)
    tkMessageBox.showinfo("Result", str(result))
```

Where `content` is your operation. If you want to add/remove acceptable characters, just edit the `numbersandoperatorslist`, and don't forget to add spaces between the characters.

Comment: Thanks for replying mate, this suggestion works but now I've got another issue which is how to evaluate entry inputs and accept only numbers and display a message for the user that is input is not valuable. I am trying to work on validatecommand but it is not working. unfortunately things in tkinter are different.

Comment: @Janomannan: That's easy. Replace the operation function for the new response.

Comment: @Jannomannan: Sorry for the time. I just took a little while. _response_ wasn't the correct word; it should be _answer_.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your efforts, I couldn't manage with your codes as I didn't know how to arrange it due to some arithmetic operations in codes. I found another way but it is partly working. example.

Comment: @Jannomannan: What kind of operators? Things like square roots? Then set `numbersandoperatorslist` to `"1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 0 + - = * / V".split(" ")`. This is the same as `["1", '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', '0', '-', '=', '+', '*', '/', 'V']`, and add before the `eval` line to replace any 'V' with `math.sqrt(` _`V value`_ `)`, and then go on the `eval`, etc.